# Placing two "float:right" images above one another

Tags: html

When I use

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <img style="float:right" src="image1.svg">
    </p>
    <p>
      <img style="float:right" src="image2.svg">
    </p>
    <p>
        text...
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

with image1.svg containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="200" height="200"
     viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     version="1.1">
<g>
    <path d="M 10 10 L 190 10 L 100 190 z"
          fill="cyan" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" />
</g>
</svg>
```

and image2.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="200" height="200"
     viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     version="1.1">
<g>
    <path d="M 10 10 L 190 10 L 190 190 L 10 190 z"
          fill="cyan" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" />
</g>
</svg>
```

the two SVG images are placed side-by-side despite the `</p><p>`. Replacing these with `</br>` does not help. How do I force the two images to be placed above one another? Needless to say, I would like to avoid building a composition of the two images.

Comment: Why are you floating them if you don't want one to be beside the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have them floated individually, you want to add `clear: right;` to the style for both of them.

If you're happy to float them both together, then wrap their enclosing paragraphs in a single DIV and float that to the right.

Comment: Fleshed out code for second idea below. Couldn't apply the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by combining the images in one containing element and floating that element right, while applying a `clear:both` style to the individual images themselves.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/NZuJk/1/)

```
<p id="images">
    <img style="float:right" src="image1.svg" />
    <img style="float:right" src="image2.svg" />
</p>
<p>
    text...
</p>

#images{
    float:right;
}
#images img{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @Calef - not sure how to better explain... Put both images into a single parent element. Float that parent element right. `clear:both` of the images them selves. The example link works, and you can examine the code there. Helps?

Comment: I generally assume that CSS files are for features that will appear repeatedly. One-shot display methods should instead appear directly in html, whenever possible. Feel free to disagree. In this instance, the css file is already polished and I don't really want to touch it for this small addition. To do so would mean I have to debug everywhere else where the CSS file is used. Principle 2 (let's call it): isolate in a css file features that will be included in multiple html files.

Answer (score 1):

Div is a nice hint.

Notes:

1. It is unnecessary to alter the (already fine-tuned) css file, which for simplicity is not included here).
2. It is unnecessary to clear:right the images, just not add them in the firstplace.

> ```
> <html>
>   <body>
>     <div style="float:right">
>       <p>
>         <img src="image1.svg">
>       </p>
>       <p>
>         <img src="image2.svg">
>       </p>
>     </div>
>     <p>
>         text...
>     </p>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: This should be an edit to your question, not an answer. Please edit your post and delete this answer.